# Do I Need To Reference Indirect DLLs

Tags: c#

Suppose I have DLLA which is a standalone library that contains classes I use

I have DLLB that references DLLA

I now have DLLC that references DLLB - Why is it that DLLC also needs a reference to DLLA?

Can I not have VS2005 build a dll which contains all the assemblies it needs embedded inside it?

Answer (score 2):

You will need a reference to DLLA if DLLC uses types from DLLA. This is the case if return types or input exposed by types in DLLB are defined in DLLA.

This is also the case if types in DLLB derive from types in DLLA.

You may also [run into this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1254078/clscomplianttrue-drags-in-unused-references).

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4445213/net-inheritance-automatic-dependency-referencing-behavior-issue (asked after this question, linked for completeness).