# .Net Inheritance - Automatic dependency referencing behavior issue

Tags: c#, inheritance, reference, dependencies

I've come across a strange issue that I've just now noticed.

If you have a solution with 3 projects

** NOTE Edited after discussion **

Project LibA - Has a ClassA

```
namespace LibA
{
    public class ClassA
    {
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return "The logic in class A!";
        }
    }
}
```

Project LibB - Has a ClassB

```
using LibA;

namespace LibB
{
    public class ClassB
    {
        public ClassA a;

        public ClassB()
        {
            a = new ClassA();
        }

        public object Foo()
        {
            return a;
        }
    }
}
```

Project LibC - Has a ClassC

```
using LibB;

namespace LibC
{
    public class ClassC
    {
        public ClassB b;

        public ClassC()
        {
            b = new ClassB();
        }

        public object Foo()
        {
            return b.Foo();
        }
    }
}
```

Finally a test driver

```
using System;
using LibC;

namespace Shell
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ClassC c = new ClassC();
            Console.WriteLine(c.Foo());
        }
    }
}
```

Now if you compile this, everything will work perfectly. If you examine the contents of LibC's binary folder, you'll see that it automatically rolled through the chain of dependencies to determine that it needed to pull in LibA and LibB

However, if you alter ClassB to inherit from class A
such as

```
using LibA;

namespace LibB
{
    public class ClassB : ClassA
    {
        ClassA a;
    }
}
```

attempt to compile, you'll get the error

> Error 2 The type 'LibA.ClassA' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'LibA, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.

** Original Question **

Does anyone know why (whether it is msbuild or visual studio) it is smart enough to reference LibA when ClassA a member of ClassB, but it isn't smart enough to reference LibA when ClassA is the base class of ClassB?

I know it's nitpicky, but I would really appreciate some consistent behavior

** Amended Question with these observed tests **

I'm hearing what some define as "direct" or "indirect" references. However, direct is clearly not just the visibility scoping, it seems to be inheritance and actual usage of a type.

Without inheritance, the test driver is smart enough to resolve and automatically reference LibA, LibB and LibC.

There is a **public** member ClassA visible in ClassB and yet that alone doesn't produce the compilation/linking error.

The debugger definitely resolves ClassA from the test driver, so it clearly loaded the correct assembly.

So with all that in mind. I get the whole "direct" and "indirect" stuff now.

The thing that is still not clicking to me why the linker/compiler/IDE doesn't at least try to automatically reference the dependencies of a referenced library in an "direct" scenario? It's clearly smart enough to know the dependencies are there and reference them in an "indirect" scenario.

Comment: Most definitely interesting. As a former VB.NET guy this is something I can't understand. The VB.NET compiler is smart enough to chain project dependencies; why the C# compiler isn't?

Answer (score 4):

This is consistent behaviour. The first one is a simple reference, the second one is inheritance.

If an assembly is compiled and a class inherits from a class in another assembly, that reference is required to construct it.

`LibB` only contains the information that is **added** in the class definition of `ClassB`, it doesn't copy everything from `LibA` (this would produce inconsistent code if `LibA` is updated and `ClassA` is changed while doing that, `LibB` would still contain the old information).

So to use an inherited class definition in `LibC`, it needs both the information from `LibA` (for `ClassA`) and `LibB` (`ClassB`) to construct it, thus a direct reference to `LibA` is needed.

In the example, all references to classes of different assemblies are private, thus only the next level is neeed (`ClassC` doesn't need to know about `ClassA` as there is no direct usage of that class). If the usage of `ClassA` in `ClassB` was a public field or propety, `ClassC` would have a direct reference to `ClassA` and would need a direct reference to that class definition as well (reference to `LibA` from `LibC`).

In a different form, this is also the case in the inheritance example. `ClassC` has a direct reference to `ClassA` (due to `ClassB` inherting from `ClassA`), thus a reference to the declaring assembly (namely `LibA`) is needed to construct the full class definition.

Comment: I understand why inheriting needs the information. I'm wondering why LibC automatically copies both LibA and LibB, if it is a member and why it doesn't automatically copy LibA and LibB if it's inheriting

Comment: Because in the case of reference only `LibB` needs the information of `LibA` (be aware that in all cases the referenced class is a private field so not exposed to the outside, so using classes don't need to know about it). In the inheritance case however, `ClassB` is still a member of `ClassC`, but `ClassB` inherits `ClassA`, thus `ClassC` needs to know about `ClassA` as well (to construct the full class definition).

Comment: On this note, I exposed ClassA as a public variable in ClassB and it still automatically referenced LibA in LibC. However, to your point, when I did attempt to do something with that public variable it then did ask to explicitly reference LibA from LibC.

Comment: You didn't expose `ClassA`, you exposed it as an object. Thus you don't have a reference to `ClassA` in `ClassC`. Please exchange `object` for `ClassA` in your method.

Comment: and I get the "direct/indirect" thing now. Regardless of changing foo to return ClassA, I want to know what is the problem of having VS auto reference whether it is direct or indirect?

Comment: A direct reference requires an actual reference in the project settings and the assembly. Visual Studio could do that, but the programmer would lose control. Imagine you referenced an assembly, and realize that it was the wrong one. That assembly has three direct dependencies. Now you have to remove all four references from your project. Cumbersome action, isn't it?

Comment: Haha, true. However, I'd still like the option. I'd rather remove extra dependency dlls than to add the extra dependency dlls. Perhaps a IDE library switch that says "automagically add"

Answer (score 0):

> I know it's nitpicky, but I would
>   really appreciate some consistent
>   behavior

It is consistant. You must reference any type that you use directly. Indirect references are resolved transparently.

Comment: what are you considering an indirect reference? As you can see in my revision of class B, it is directly referencing class A

Comment: But `ClassC` doesn't know about `ClassA`, so no direct reference is needed. (`ClassA` is a private field of `ClassB`, thus not visible to `ClassC`).

Answer (score 0):

In the first scenario, you are just **using the ClassA**. So, it does not need the resource at compile time, just at run time.

In the second scenario, you are **inheriting from ClassA**, so, its definition and information is needed by the compiler in order to build the final assembly.

In the first scenario, VisualStudio **copies the referenced DLL into the output directory**, because it knows you'll need it there.

In the second scenario, VisualStudio does not **add the reference to the project**, and that's I assume, your main doubt. I guess it's meant that way in order to avoid problems by being intrusive in your project. But, I'm just guessing...