# Project reference needed on build server but not when built locally

Tags: c#, entity-framework, msbuild, nunit

I've a unit test that builds fine locally but when on the TeamCity integration server it fails citing a reference needed to EF. The test doesn't use EF directly but the library its testing does.

The EF dll is being deployed to the test projects bin folder so its not a matter of not finding it. EF is referenced via nu-get and is version 6.0.2 (though the version in the properties window shows 6.0.0.0 which may be just the major version number).

I've other test projects with the same configuration which are not having this issue.

I'm looking for ideas for a solution.

I can build the project using msbuild manually and get the same error on the integration server but not locally. We can add the nu-get ref to the test project and it builds fine but that's not the correct solution.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: What does msbuild log say? And could you show relevant piece of .csproj file?

Comment: error CS0012: The type 'System.Data.Entity.DbContext' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.

Comment: As long as you can reproduce it by manually running msbuild I would suggest to run it with detailed logging (`/v:d` or even `/v:diag`) and compare outputs of two builds - successful and non-successful. It should reveal the difference in reference resolving, etc. Do you have same .NET Framework and same tools versions installed on local PC and build server? It might also cause difference.

Comment: We've determined its related to inheritance similar to this question
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4445213/net-inheritance-automatic-dependency-referencing-behavior-issue

I don't understand why its not consistently asking for that reference in all the other Test projects that use the same or similar type libraries