# Mandelbug: Unwanted transitive assembly references required by compiler; CLS compliance; visibility

Tags: c#, .net, dependencies, .net-assembly, cls-compliant

### Overview

Debugging an interesting bug, I stripped down a solution to its bare bones in an attempt to isolate it.  The issue manifests itself with a classic build error (assembly not referenced).

What's interesting is that no types from the assembly in question are used in the assembly that cannot be built.  Moving `using` statements and removing CLS compliance attributes make the error disappear, implying that an obscure symbol visibility rule is in effect (probably).

### Code

```
Mandelbug/
|-- Mandelbug.sln
`-- src
    |-- Bar
    |   |-- Bar.csproj
    |   `-- Beta.cs
    |-- Baz
    |   |-- Baz.csproj
    |   |-- Gamma.cs
    |   `-- Properties
    |       `-- AssemblyInfo.cs
    `-- Foo
        |-- Alpha.cs
        `-- Foo.csproj
```

*Except for the project (`csproj`) files, the entire codebase is shown here, line-by-line.*

**Foo/Alpha.cs**

```
namespace Foo {
    public class Alpha : Bar.Beta { }
}
```

**Bar/Beta.cs**

```
namespace Bar {
    public class Beta { }
}
```

**Baz/Gamma.cs**

```
namespace Foo {
    using System;
    public class Gamma { }
}
```

**Baz/Properties/AssemblyInfo.cs**

```
[assembly: System.CLSCompliant(true)]
```

### Dependencies

[image]

All projects reference `System` and `System.Core`.
`Baz` references `Foo`.
`Foo` references `Bar`.

`Foo.Alpha` needs the dependency to **inherit** from `Bar.Beta`.
`Baz.Gamma` needs the dependency for other types in `Foo` in the real solution (unrelated to `Alpha`).  None are used in this stripped down solution, yet the issue still appears.

### Compilation error

Description: `The type 'Bar.Beta' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'Bar, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.`
File: `src\Baz\Gamma.cs`
Line: `1`
Column: `11`
Project: `Baz`

### Behavior

The problem disappears when:

1. Placing the `using` statement in `Gamma` outside the `Foo` namespace block.
2. Removing the `CLSCompliant` attribute for the `Baz` assembly.
3. `Alpha` does not inherit from `Beta` (even if `Foo` still references `Bar` and `Alpha` still uses `Beta` in other ways, for example by composing it).
4. `Foo` is out of reach from `Gamma` (for example by changing `Gamma`'s namespace to `Baz`).
5. A reference to `Bar` is added in `Baz`.

It doesn't matter if the other projects are CLS compliant or not.  In the real solution they are.
The target framework doesn't seem to influence that behavior.
It doesn't matter what namespace we import in the `Gamma.cs` namespace block, we're writing `using System;` here, but it could be anything.  Removing all `using` statements (or placing them outside the namespace block) makes the problem go away, as mentioned above.

### Questions

1. What CLS rule affects that behavior?
2. Why does placing the `using` statement inside or outside the namespace block affects that behavior?
3. This is not just a curiosity, we actually have a project with such a transitive dependency -- should we add the reference to `Bar` even though it doesn't make sense? (We're not using the `Alpha` inherited type.)

### Notes

I know the compiler is never wrong, but it still looks like some serious voodoo when you don't know what's going on (especially the `using` statement placement thing).  I've skimmed the I.11 section of ECMA-335 (CLI) which contains a reference of CLS rules, but I can't pinpoint which one is the one I should understand but obviously don't.

Should the issue not be obvious, you should be able to reproduce it consistently by simply copying the code verbatim in empty C# projects and adding the same references.

Comment: I can sort of see how it happened, nothing to nail to a wall.  File a bug report at connect.microsoft.com.  And do consider removing the attribute, it stopped making sense 9 years ago.

Comment: @HansPassant: Thanks, I'll probably do that. Still, although I'm not one of them, I'd imagine many people might not agree on your statement about CLS compliance, especially when it comes to libraries. Also, I think I've found a [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1254078) - I'll investigate in details tomorrow and properly mark it as such if it's right. The answers there don't seem too conclusive at first glance though, I hope I'm wrong.

Comment: [Filed](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/920175/cls-compliance-and-build-time-transitive-dependency-requirements).

Comment: Fixed in Roslyn (see bug report).